# How to subscribe to activity livedata viewmodel from fragment? Android

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

I am making a call to retreive data from `MainActivity` throught `MainViewModel`. The data saves in `MainViewModel` live data. But I need `SomeFragment` observe this data from `MainViewModel`. How can I achieve this?

My View Model code

```
    class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val myRepository : MyRepository = MyRepositoryImpl()

    private val data: MutableLiveData<Data> = MutableLiveData()
    val dataResult: LiveData<Data> = data

    suspend fun getCoordinates(param: String){
        val dataApiResult = MyRepository.getData(param)
        data.postValue(dataApiResult)
    }
}
```

And my Fragment code

```
    class MyFragment : Fragment() {

    private val mainViewModel: MainViewModel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        mainViewModel.dataResult.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            Log.d("tag", "SUPPOSE TO COME HERE")
        })
    }
```

If I observe that live data in Activity it works. In fragment it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that in the host `MainActivity` i init viewmodel the wrong way. By mistake i did

```
    private val mainViewModel: MainViewModel = MainViewModel()
```

instead of correct

```
    private val mainViewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels()
```

Answer (score 0):

**instaed of**

```
val mainViewModel: MainViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

**use**

```
val mainViewModel by viewModels<MainViewModel>()
```

this is an extension function on the fragment class

you can find it in this dependency

```
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.6.0-alpha03"
```

Comment: no its not trigger :( Why then `activityViewModels` been created. On this link it says the solution is https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-shared-viewmodel#4